# PYTHON: Split list of attribute value pairs into multi-key dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm attempting to convert

```
l = ['attr0=val1, val2', 'attr1=val3,val4']
```

to

```
d = {attr0: [val1, val2]; attr1: [val3, val4]}
```

efficiently/pythonically. Anyone know of a concise way to do so?

I'm trying something like:

```
d = {}
for str in l:
    k = str.split('=')[0]
    v = str.split('=')[1]
    d[k] = []
    for item in v.split(','):
        d[k].append(item)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, your dictionary is invalid. Is that supposed to be a list of values `[val1, val2]`? Please ensure you at least provide the proper syntax of your expected output.

Comment: Update your question with the details. Also, please provide your own coding attempt at this.

Comment: sorry, meant for it to be a list of values, inadvertently left out the brackets

Comment: Why are you splitting on ':' when your example is using '='?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In[9]: test = ['attr0=val1, val2', 'attr1=val3,val4']
In[10]: result = {}
   ...: for attribute in test:
   ...:     key, value = attribute.split('=')
   ...:     result[key] = [a.strip() for a in value.split(',')]
   ...: 
In[11]: result
Out[11]: {'attr0': ['val1', 'val2'], 'attr1': ['val3', 'val4']}
```

Comment: For my use, it's safe to assume attr0 is guaranteed to be unique, thanks!

Comment: @Mike Ok, thanks for clarifying! The reason I had to use a list comprehension was the first values are separated by `", "` but the second values are only separated by `","`. If you could guarantee that they have the same delimiter, you could get rid of the list comprehension which strips the excess whitespace too. That would leave you with `result[key] = value.split(',')  # or split(', ')`